# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name when trying to insert data in database (C#, Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, sql, database

First I would like to say that I thought that my problem was easily solved but after a lot of trying and searching I am not making any progress (I am also a complete beginner when it comes to databases).

I made a database with Microsoft SQL Server and called it UltimatePokerDB.
I added a table MyTable
I added two columns sevenKeys and sevenValues

this is visible in Visual Studio
[Image of my Server Explorer in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76RRp.png)

and makes this SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    [sevenKeys] BINARY(56) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [SevenValues] BINARY(48) NOT NULL
)
```

I have the following code written in my Main method

```
            string provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            string connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            byte[] one = new byte[7];
            byte[] two = new byte[6];

            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                string sql = "insert into MyTable (sevenKeys, sevenValues) values(@first,@last)";
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", one);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", two);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("row inserted");
                }
            }
```

I get an error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and it says: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'MyTable'.'

Basically Im giving it the wrong name but I have no clue what it wants me to do...

Comment: You are not quering the correct database. You are on the master, and the table MyTable doesn't exists there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specified in your connection string to use the Database `master`. You should probably be using the database your table is in, which is probably not `master`. In fact it looks like it should be `UltimatePokerDB` from your screenshot.

Comment: i changed my connection string and it now indeed does work, thank you!